# Stateless authorization of API endpoints with express and JWT

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, jwt

I'm creating a REST API to store some information about some items.
It is nothing highly sensitive or anything but I still want to properly secure it. Also in regards of maybe having to secure something else in the future.

To sign the users in I'm using OIDC with Google and Azure to retrieve user information from the user information endpoint. After that I want to store the user in a database along with their permissions. For them to access the API I want to generate and sign a JWT Access Token and Refresh Token. So far so good.

I want the acces to the API to be stateless (with the Access Token) for scalability. I'm not so much worried about the sign in process being stateless. The refreshing of Access Tokens via the Refresh Token also doesn't have to be stateless, but it would be nice to have.

I was reading through some other questions and articles online regarding XSS and CSRF. To me it all boiled down to two things:

1. Don't use local or session storage to prevent XSS-Attacks grabbing tokens stored there. Solution seemed to be to use cookies (http only cookies, samesite).
2. Don't use cookies as to prevent CSRF.

I'm now kind of stuck because the two options seem to recommend not using either.
I thought about how this might be solvable and was reading through OWASP recommendations mentioning generating a fingerprint during sign in and storing it in the JWT as user context.
In my mind I have the following process.

1. Sign the user in using OIDC and receive information about the user from the user endpoint.
2. Look up the user in the database and get their permissions.
3. Create a unique fingerprint for the user.
4. Store the fingerprint in a hardened cookie (http only, secure, samesite).
5. Create a JWT Access Token using the users id, permissions and an encrypted string of the fingerprint.
6. Create a JWT Refresh Token using the users id, permissions and an encrypted string of the fingerprint.
7. Sign both JWTs.
8. Return the Tokens to the client with the hardened cookie set.

Now if the user wants to access a protected resource he sets the Authorization Header with the Access Token and sends the request, which will then also include the hardened cookie. The server can decrypt the fingerprint from the Access Token and compare it to the fingerprint from the cookie.
If the user wants to use the Refresh Token to get an expired Access Token the fingerprint would also be validated before issuing a new Access Token.
Access Tokens would be short lived e.g. 15 minutes. Refresh Tokens would be long lived e.g. 1 day.

In my mind this solves both problems:

1. Leaking of the tokens would be useless without also having the fingerprint from the cookie or the cookie itself.
2. Leaking the cookie via something like CSRF would be useless as the Tokens would not be available.

Only if an attacker would simultaneously get hold of both he would be able to have access.

My questions are:

1. Am I overlooking something?
2. What would be a good way to generate this fingerprint? Use the "sub" from the user endpoint?

Thanks for your help already!

Comment: Your "fingerprint" seems to play the role of a [proof-of-possession key](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7800.html), would you agree?

Comment: Yes, I'm not that experienced with all crypographic methods but I got the Idea for what i described from the PKCE from OAuth. So something that proofs, that the Client is also the one who initially started the request or in my case who initially signed in.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I've scrolled through your link. The keywould typically be stored in the "cnf" calim of the JWT. Because I want to have a key which is not prone to XSS I would store this key in a http-only cookie and have the signature in the JWT or vice versa. Would you say this solves my described problem (I think yes)?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand why such a key is not prone to XSS. With XSS, attackers can cause your site to make a request, which would contain the http-only same-site cookie. XSS means that attackers can change the effective Javascript code on your site. What you mean is probably CSRF.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I guess if Javascript was to be injected and they would make a request to my service in the script with the token it would work. Aren't http only cookies managed by the browser? If the attacker was to make a request to not-my-site.com from Javascript, wouldn’t the browser not send the same-site cookie? I was worried of both, token and secret being leaked. To mitigate your describe case: Is there anything to prevent that, except from trying hard at mitigating XSS in the first place?